# Sending a jquery array through AJAX to a c# ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create an Array in jquery and pass it to an MVC controller which is accepting an Object with an ObseverableCollection inside of it.  I am having an issue with getting the Observable to accept my array.

I am having an issue with creating the array, but also passing it through AJAX to an ObservableCollection.  Member: is the observable and Name: is just a string inside the Object. Any Ideas?

Here is my jquery code:

```
var memberCollection = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({ Members: [] });

click: function (e) {
                var myId = e.dataItem.AdId;
                memberCollection.Members.push(myId)
            }
```

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: MobileHomePath + "AddGroup",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            Name: this.get("groupName"),
            Members:  memberCollection
        },
    }).success(function (data) {
        if (data != "fail") {
            alert("Awesome");
        }
        else {
            app.hideLoading();
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddGroup(GroupObj obj) 
    {
       return Content("");
    }
```

Object:

```
public class GroupObj
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having exactly?  Please describe the issue more precisely.

Comment: I edited my original post

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Thanks for future answers!